# get totalprice from multiple prices in php/sql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I stumpled across a little problem with a list of prices. 
I have a price that is calculated from a productprice * quantity which works as intended, but what I want is the sum of all the prices that have been calculated ie.

price1 = productprice1 * 1 = 500
price2 = productprice2 * 2 = 2000

totalprice = price1 + price1 = 2500

The price for each line in the loop is calculated with this:

```
$price = $fields_row["field_qty"] * $fields_row["field_price"];
```

How can I get the total sum of $price when it is finished running through the loop?

Comment: show your query it will done on your sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUM is a method SQL. Example :

```
SELECT SUM(expression )
FROM tables
WHERE predicates;
```

or you make it in php for example:

```
$sum = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sum += $amount[ $row['id'] ];
}
```

Hopes it will help you

Comment: Argh... For the most time the solution is so close it is easily overlooked :)

Solved it with

$sum = 0;
$sum += $price;

Thanks for the help! :)